# Is there a manifold with no embedded incompressible surface?

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I mean, in any 3-manidold there is an embedded disk (since locally we have $\mathbb{R}^3$ and one can find a disk in $\mathbb{R}^3$) and disk will always be an incompressible surface. Why am I wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Did someone say you were wrong? If so, maybe they meant surface without boundary, which a disk is not?

Comment: @OsamaGhani I am confused, becauce in that case definition of Haken manifold (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haken_manifold) has redundant information - since any compact irreducible 3-manifold automatically contains a disk, thus an incompressible surface. Or Haken manifolds must contain exactly incompressible surface without boundary?

Comment: I incorrectly assumed incompressible was another word for non-contractible. If you read the links, you can see first off, the incompressible surface has to be a surface without boundary, so a disk is not an example.

Comment: @OsamaGhani Quite the opposite, this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incompressible_surface gives an example of Seifert surface with boundary which is incompressible. Why do you think that incompressible surface must have no boundary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia article does not do a very good job here, which, I think, is the source of your confusion.

1. Suppose that $S$ is a closed (compact, with empty boundary), 2-sided surface embedded in a (boundaryless) 3-manifold $M$. Such a surface $S$ is called **compressible** in $M$, if it is either a 2-dimensional sphere bounding a 3-ball in $M$, or $S$ contains a simple loop $c$ which bounds an embedded disk $D$ in $M$ such that $D\cap S= c$. Accordingly, $S$ is called **incompressible** if it is not compressible. In particular, a 2-dimensional disk in $M$ will fail the definition of an incompressible surface.
2. The notion of an incompressible surface also makes sense in the category of manifolds with boundary, namely, assuming that
   $M$ be a 3-dimensional manifold (possibly with boundary) and $S$ a (for simplicity, compact) 2-sided
   **properly embedded,** surface in $M$ (properly embedded here means that $\partial S= S\cap \partial M$). The definition is the same as above, or it can be strengthened to the one of a **[boundary-incompressible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary-incompressible_surface) surface.**

As for your example of a 2-dimensional disk $D$ in a 3-manifold $M$: It will never be incompressible (it is a good exercise to see why). However, it can be *boundary-incompressible,* if it is properly embedded in $M$ and there is no 3-dimensional ball $B\subset M$ whose boundary is a union of two disks: One is $D$  and the other is in $\partial M$.

As for your title question: Yes, there are many  manifolds (even closed ones) without incompressible surfaces, for instance, $S^3$, small Seifert manifolds, small hyperbolic manifolds...